# SnakeMake fails with non-zero exit code that runs fine outside of snakemake

Tags: conda, snakemake, seq

I am trying to build a pipeline for Chip-Seq analysis using Snakemake.  The first step in this pipeline is gathering the .sra files. 
I have a very simple rule which calls the prefetch command from sra-tools.  When I run the snakemake file I get the following output

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       get_sra_num
        1

[Thu May 14 17:15:26 2020]
rule get_sra_num:
    output: SRR11551735/SRR11551735.sra
    jobid: 0
    wildcards: sra_num=11551735

[Thu May 14 17:15:26 2020]
Error in rule get_sra_num:
    jobid: 0
    output: SRR11551735/SRR11551735.sra
    conda-env: /storage/htc/bdm/Melanoma/Chips/.snakemake/conda/ca9cfc90
    shell:

                prefetch SRR11551735

        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

However, if I run the command 
`prefetch SRR11551735` in a terminal with the same conda environment then the command succeeds without notifying a non zero exit code.  Any suggestions?

If they are of any help here is the conda environment

```
name: ralp
channels:
- bioconda
- mrh8x5
- conda_gc_test
- defaults
dependencies:
- ncbi-ngs-sdk=2.10.0=hdf6179e_0
- perl-app-cpanminus=1.7044=pl526_1
- perl-business-isbn=3.004=pl526_0
- perl-business-isbn-data=20140910.003=pl526_0
- perl-carp=1.38=pl526_3
- perl-constant=1.33=pl526_1
- perl-data-dumper=2.173=pl526_0
- perl-encode=2.88=pl526_1
- perl-exporter=5.72=pl526_1
- perl-extutils-makemaker=7.36=pl526_1
- perl-file-path=2.16=pl526_0
- perl-file-temp=0.2304=pl526_2
- perl-mime-base64=3.15=pl526_1
- perl-parent=0.236=pl526_1
- perl-uri=1.76=pl526_0
- perl-xml-libxml=2.0132=pl526h7ec2d77_1
- perl-xml-namespacesupport=1.12=pl526_0
- perl-xml-sax=1.02=pl526_0
- perl-xml-sax-base=1.09=pl526_0
- perl-xsloader=0.24=pl526_0
- sra-tools=2.10.0=pl526he1b5a44_0
- _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
- libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
- libiconv=1.15=h63c8f33_5
- libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
- libxml2=2.9.9=hea5a465_1
- perl=5.26.2=h14c3975_0
- xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
- zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
prefix: /storage/hpc/data/mrh8x5/miniconda/envs/ralp
```

and the Snakefile rule

```
small_chip_SRAs = [11551734, 11551735]

rule all:
        input:
                expand("FAST_Q/SRR{SRAs}.fastq", SRAs=small_chip_SRAs)

rule get_sra_num:
        conda:
                "workflow/envs/chip_env.yml"
        output:
                sra_file="SRR{sra_num}/SRR{sra_num}.sra"
        threads:1
        shell:'''
                prefetch SRR{wildcards.sra_num}
                '''

rule get_fast_q:
        conda:
                "workflow/envs/chip_env.yml"
        input:
                sra_file="SRR{sra_num}/SRR{sra_num}.sra"
        output:
                fq="FAST_Q/SRR{sra_num}.fastq"
        threads:1
        shell:'''
                fastq-dump {input.sra_file} -O FAST_Q
```

Comment: Where is the error message? There should be an error message for the `prefetch` not just Snakemake's report that a step failed.

Comment: this is all that is in the slurm-*.out file.  Where should that message be?

Comment: Try logging into an interactive node on the slurm cluster via srun. See if you can the command succesfully there.

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande as stated in the question I have done this already and it runs without error in that scenario "However, if I run the command  prefetch SRR11551735 in a terminal with the same Conda environment then the command succeeds without notifying a non zero exit code."

Comment: @ChunkyT you didn't state it's from an interactive node though... Since somehow no error message appears in the slurm out, why dont you capture it and send it to a log to see what the error message is?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande.  Thank you for your help.  when I run from an interactive node there is no error.  the outputs are
'''
2020-05-17T01:07:58 prefetch.2.10.0: 1) Downloading 'SRR11551743'...
2020-05-17T01:07:58 prefetch.2.10.0:  Downloading via https...
2020-05-17T01:10:46 prefetch.2.10.0:  https download succeed
2020-05-17T01:10:46 prefetch.2.10.0: 1) 'SRR11551743' was downloaded successfully
2020-05-17T01:10:46 prefetch.2.10.0: 'SRR11551743' has 0 unresolved dependencies
''''  After doing this all the expected files are present. The problem only happens when run with SnakeMake.

Comment: @ChunkyT not sure... One thing to note is that the rule fails instantly. I do not see any print that snakemake is activating the conda environment, but maybe that's because you are using a new snakemake version, since I also never seen conda-env in the printed rule before.. What if you install sra-tools in your snakemake environment and run it without --use-conda? Does it then work?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande the terminal shos that it is using the conda environment.
"Error in rule get_sra_num:
    jobid: 0
    output: SRR11551735/SRR11551735.sra
    conda-env: /storage/htc/bdm/Melanoma/Chips/.snakemake/conda/ca9cfc90
    shell:".

Comment: How was Snakemake configured to work with SLURM? It sounds like the job might be running in a non-login bash session and perhaps does not have `conda activate` defined. Maybe try running a test rule that tries something like `conda activate --help &> test.log`.